# Switching from Google Maps API to Here Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, here-api

Previously I was using Google Maps API for the map interface, I am now switching over to Here Maps API. My application uses struts and JSP. Previously, with google maps i loaded a script and call back as so:

```
function loadGoogleMapsAPIScript(){
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
var language = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("lang");

//we should use the same protocol as the web page: http or https.
var href = window.location.href;
protocol = href.substr(0, href.indexOf(':'));

var src = protocol+"://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js";
src += "?v=3"; //Add google maps api version.
src += "&sensor=false"; // sensor should always be false here.
src += "&callback=google_maps_callback"; //add callback function. This function will be called
                                        //after the script load successful.
src += "&language="+language;           //add language.
//}
script.setAttribute("src", src);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Callback function:

```
function google_maps_callback(){
var map_opt = {
    zoom: your_location.map_zoom,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var obj = your_location.map_obj;
var map = new google.maps.Map(obj, map_opt);
var infowin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (var i =0; i < your_location.count; i++){
    bounds = add_marker(map, i, infowin, bounds);
}

if (your_location.count>0){
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(
        map,"bounds_changed",
        function(event){
            if(map.getZoom()>your_location.map_zoom){
                map.setZoom(your_location.map_zoom);
            }
        }
    );
}else{
    map.setZoom(1);
}

}
```

I have created a loadHereMapsAPIScript function as so:

```
function loadHereMapsAPIScript(){

var script1 = document.createElement("script1");
script1.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
script1.setAttribute("src","http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js");
document.getElementByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script1);

var script2 = document.createElement("script2");
script2.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
script2.setAttribute("src","http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js");
document.getElementByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script2);

}
```

how would i add a call back method into the loadHereMapsAPIScript to call a new function here_maps callback() that does the same thing as google_maps_callback(). Would I first define platform, for the center would i use setCenter? :

```
function here_maps_callback(){
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    app_id: 'myAPIId',
    app_code: 'myAPICode'
    useCIT: true,
    useHTTPS: true
})
var map_opt = {
    zoom: clients_location.map_zoom,
    center: new H.geo.Point(0,0),

}
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have provided the completed call back function for Here Maps that mimics the google call back function. This coupled with the answer below given by Dr.Molle works completely.

```
function here_maps_callback(){
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    app_id: 'your-app-id',
    app_code: 'your-app.code',
    useCIT: true,
    useHTTPS: true
});

var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

var obj = your_location.map_obj;

var map = new H.Map(
     obj,
     defaultLayers.normal.map,
     {
         zoom:your_location.map_zoom,
         center: {lat:0,lng:0}
     });
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map,defaultLayers);

for (var i =0; i < your_location.count; i++){
    add_marker_here(map,index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to load mapsjs-core.js twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HERE-API doesn't implement a callback like the google-maps-API does, you need to handle it on your own.

When you load a script asynchronously you may add a `onload`-handler to the script(s) where you run the callback.

But when you use HERE you must also keep a specific loading-order, because there are dependencies for the modules.

E.g. when you load the **service**-module you must ensure that the **core**-module has already been loaded.(see https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/overview.html#modules for details)

An option is to use a kind of chain to load the modules, possible implementation:

```
    function loadHereMapsAPIScript(ss){   
         if(!ss.length)return;
         var s=ss.shift();

         if(typeof s==='function'){
            //run the callback
            s();
            return;
         }
         if(typeof s!=='string')return;
         //load a module
         var script=document.createElement("script");
         script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
         document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
         script.onload=function(){loadHereMapsAPIScript(ss);}
         script.setAttribute('src',s);  
   }

   loadHereMapsAPIScript(
     [
       //the desired modules 
       'http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js',
       'http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js',
       //the callback to be executed when all modules have been loaded
       here_maps_callback                      
    ]
   );
```

Comment: What do you mean by (ss)

Comment: would the second statement with the script URLs and the call back be called in my jsp, which then would give those parameters to the function loadHereMapsApi?

Comment: `ss` ist the argument passed to the function(the array with the URLs)... the 2nd statement is the function call.